# How do I add a Linode-hosted subdomain to a Namecheap domain hosted on NearlyFreeSpeech?

Tags: domain-name-system, subdomain

I have the domain `somedomain.com` registered with Namecheap. NearlyFreeSpeech hosts the site.

I've added `ns.phx1.nearlyfreespeech.net` and
`ns.phx2.nearlyfreespeech.net` to that domain's custom nameservers
list on Namecheap.

I'd like to add a subdomain
"test" so that `test.somedomain.com` goes to my Linode box. Where must I change/add records to accomplish this?

**Update**

I added A and AAAA records to my NearlyFreeSpeech DNS settings.

My A record looks kinda like this:

`test.somedomain.com A MY.IP.ADDRESS.HERE`

But when I go to `test.somedomain.com`, I get a `Bad Request (400)` error.

**Update 2**

I'm using nginx. I followed Linode's [tutorial](https://www.linode.com/docs/web-servers/nginx/deploy-django-applications-using-uwsgi-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04/) on setting up a Django project on an Ubuntu 14.04 box.

Maybe I configured the [hostname file](https://www.linode.com/docs/getting-started/#set-the-hostname) wrong?

Here's what's in my `/etc/hosts`:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost.localdomain   loclhost
127.0.1.1       ubuntu.members.linode.com       ubuntu
MY.LINODE.IP.ADDRESS    dev.somedomain.com       dev
```

Comment: If you're using nearlyfreespeech.net's nameservers, you'd make the record there.

Comment: @ceejayoz Updated question

Comment: A 400 error has nothing to do with DNS and indicates some other issue. Check your logs.

Comment: @ceejayoz Updated question again